# Where is ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN configured?

Tags: testing, build, azure-devops

I am using "Publish test results" task in my build definitions since long time, but I have recently noticed that this task is giving a warning when trying to publish the test results.

```
##[warning]Failed to publish test run data:  An error occurred while sending the request.
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

When investigating in the [task source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PublishTestResultsV2/publishtestresults.ts) (this last calls [vsts-task-lib/tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/node/task.ts)), I have noticed that there is a call to [https://mysubscription.visualstudio.com/](https://%3Cmy%20subscription%3E.visualstudio.com/) using a token named ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN and I suppose this user does not have enough permissions, but I do not know where and with which user this token has been configured.

Could you please tell if you have any idea, where this ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN token is configured ?

Answer (score 0):

> Where is ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN configured?

AFAIK, the token `ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN` should be access the value from the authenticate, like personal access token (PAT).

According to the error message, it seems the remote server is behind a firewall proxy, check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts#how-do-i-configure-the-agent-to-bypass-a-web-proxy-and-connect-to-vsts) to see if the required URLs are white listed.

Besides,if you are having trouble with the publish task not using the configured proxy then you can set a variable to bypass the external executable flow. Simply set `PublishTestResults.OverrideExeFlow` to `true` in your definition variables.

Or you can check the proxy and remove it, then publish it again to check if it works for you.

Check the [similar case](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7173#issuecomment-406313541) for some more details.

Hope this helps.